# PostgreSQL PGDATA from host in Docker-System

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to run a webapp with docker-compose. I have a centos7 host running postgresql and the docker-engine. My docker-compose includes a postgresql-image and should run with the PGDATA from the host system. But everytime I run the docker-compose I get the error:

`initdb: directory "/var/lib/docker-postgresql" exists but is not empty`

The docker-compose part for the postgresql-database looks like:

```
db:
    build: ./postgres/
    container_name: ps01
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/tmp
      - /var/lib/pgsql/9.4:/var/lib/docker-postgresql    
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/docker-postgresql
```

I mount the /var/lib/pgsql/9.4 inside the Docker-Postgresql-App to /var/lib/docker-postgresql and set this path to the PGDATA-ENV.

The Dockerfile in ./postgres/ looks like:

```
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGIS_MAJOR 2.3
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.3.1+dfsg-1.pgdg80+1 

RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
           postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \
           postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR-scripts=$POSTGIS_VERSION \
           postgis=$POSTGIS_VERSION \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

What should I do to share my Postgres-Data from the host?